# Reuse values in htaccess to make more flexible code

Tags: htaccess, images, optimize

In a webshop I've build I want to make the imagename more seofriendly.
It's now a `uniqid()`, in my example the filename will be `1243`:

I've got the following working, I want the htaccess to check the following:
if `1234.jpg` exists -> redirect to the **jpg**
if `1234.jpeg` exists -> redirect to the **jpeg**
if `1234.png` exists -> redirect to the **png**
*(not in the code, but a `all 3 dont exist-> redirect to no-image.jpg` would be great)*

I have the following code (this is a simplefied version!), but I feel this could be done more efficient:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product_images/([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/%1.jpeg -f
RewriteRule ^product_images/([0-9]+) images/$1.jpeg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product_images/([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/%1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^product_images/([0-9]+) images/$1.jpg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product_images/([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/%1.png -f
RewriteRule ^product_images/([0-9]+) images/$1.png [L]
```

- All 1st lines are identical and will remain that way
- All 2nd lines are the same, apart from the `.ext`
- All 3rd lines are the same, apart from the `.ext`
- Every 3rd line has the same `.ext` as the 2nd line

My .htaccess isn't *bad*, but I have no clue where to start with this. Anyone who can push me in the right direction? I prefer explanation above the plain answer, so I can fix this myself in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, in all three rule sets the first rule is the same.  So you might benefit from nested conditions...

Here's an existing answer that should get you started.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030878/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-rewrite-conditions-in-htaccess

Also you may find it useful when optimizing your rewrites to turn on your rewrite log.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite

I think there's a danger of over-optimizing here though.  You're not likely to get a lot of real world performance improvement out of this.  I think code readability and maintainability would be the priority for something like this.